# QuickBook webconnector application not syncing data when QuickBooks is closed

Tags: php, sql, quickbooks, qbxml

I have two Quickbook company files named company_one.qbw and company_two.qbw. I have added two applications named app1 and app2 for both of this files in QuickBook webconnector.

If I run app1 with having company_one.qbw file opened in QuickBook, application syncs data from Quickbooks to my custom dashboard. Same for company_two file.

Now my issue is if I close the QuickBooks and try to sync data using webconnector app1 gives me following error "**Application requested to abort**" and it stops while app2 syncs data one time and then automatically opens the Quickbook's home page (That green page which is having 3 options to get started) and then if I try to resync app2 it asks to me close down any dialog box open.

I have added company file path in quickbook_user table as mentioned in one post. I have also granted the application to connect to the company file even if it is closed. But it's not working. So please guide me how can I implement the same.

I have tried all the possible solutions but can't figure it out. So please don't mark this as a duplicate.

I'm using QuickBooks Enterprise 19.0 version and webconnector version 2.3.0.20

Comment: Connections when QuickBooks is closed are notoriously unreliable. Don't get your hopes up on getting this to work.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. Thanks for replay. But I need to implement it anyhow. Please let me know any possible ways.