# Alternative to QuickBooks Webconnector

Tags: php, quickbooks, qbxml

I have developed one mediator which syncs data from my Volusion site to QuickBooks. During this operation system need to access the company file. For that, I have used webconnector. But for some reason, I'm not able to use it so I need an alternative to it. So please suggest me some alternatives to webconnector. I'm using QuickBooks Desktop Enterprise Edition.

Comment: I don't think you''ll have much luck finding an alternative to webconnector for what you need, what is the issue with using webconnector, are you getting an error? i'd be trying to track that down, not find an alternate to webconnector.

Comment: Agreed -- why can't you use the Web Connector?

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr., I have two application set up in webconnector. When I close QuickBooks connector failed to sync data. I have added company file path in quickbooks_user table but no luck. I have tried all possible solutions out there on the internet I even asked this question on community and S.O but I haven't found any solution and this forces me to find an alternate way.  

Here is that question. Please see this and let me know if you guys can help me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55534630/quickbook-webconnector-application-not-syncing-data-when-quickbooks-is-closed

Comment: @zack6849 Thanks for reply. Above I have stated issue which I'm encountering so please take a look and let me know if you can do something.

Comment: The limitation you're describing is _not_ a limitation of the Web Connector -- it's a limitation of QuickBooks itself. Swaping out the Web Connector is not going to help unfortunately.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. Then how can I implement it without removing the connector

Comment: The more common thing to do is leave QuickBooks open. If you need to you can have two computers, each with a separate company open.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the case, we had 3 company files at a place I used to work and had to have 3 seperate computers with the company file and web connector running at once

Comment: Perhaps I also need to do the same. Thank you guys for your valuable support.

Answer (score 0):

Intuit documents alternatives here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/get-started/get-started-with-quickbooks-web-connector#alternative-option-to-qb-web-connector

It basically boils down to: `Autofy`

But what you should really be doing here is telling us *why* the Web Connector doesn't work for you, so we can help you/understand the context.